# Can callbacks be used to configure remotes?

Tags: origen-sdk

I was reading the [Origen documentation on remotes](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/remotes/) and had a question.  When do the remote files get retrieved relative to the [Origen callbacks](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/callbacks/)?  The reason i ask is that the files we want to retrieve would be used to construct our DUT model and there are some order dependencies.

I have tried all of the existing callbacks, in an attempt to configure the remotes, with no success.

```
def pre_initialize
  Origen.app.config.remotes = [
    {
      dir: 'product',
      vault: 'ssh://git@stash.com/myproduct/origen.git',
      version: '0.1.0'
    }
  ]
end
```

If I add the remotes config to the application file it works:

```
config.remotes = [
    {
      dir: 'product',
      vault: 'ssh://git@stash.com/myproduct/origen.git',
      version: '0.1.0'
    }
  ]
```

The problem with using the config/application.rb file is that we can't keep product specific information anywhere in our application space.  We use symbolic links to map to source files that are stored in test program stash repositories.  I think we may need a new callback, please advise.

thx

** EDIT **

So I defined the remotes in another file and call the method to actually do it in the boot.rb file.  Then I placed the remote manager require method in the on_create callback but got no remotes fetched.

```
    284: def on_create
    285:   binding.pry
 => 286:   Origen.remote_manager.require!
    287: end

[1] pry(#<PPEKit::Product>)> Origen.config.remotes
=> [{:dir=>"remote_checkout", :rc_url=>"ssh://git@stash.us.com:7999/osdk/us-calendar.git", :version=>"v0.1.0"}]
[2] pry(#<PPEKit::Product>)>
origen(main):001:0>
```

It seems like the Origen.remote_manager.require! is not working. So I checked the [remotes manager file](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/blob/master/lib/origen/remote_manager.rb) and don't see how the require! method could ever work with a callback because it seems to be checking the remotes are dirty, which can never happen for a remote definition that was set after the application.rb file was loaded. So I created a resolve_remotes! method that seems to work:

```
def resolve_remotes!
  resolve_remotes
  remotes.each do |_name, remote|
    dir = workspace_of(remote)
    rc_url = remote[:rc_url] || remote[:vault]
    tag = Origen::VersionString.new(remote[:version])
    version_file = dir.to_s + '/.current_version'
    begin
      if File.exist?("#{dir}/.initial_populate_successful")
        FileUtils.rm_f(version_file) if File.exist?(version_file)
        rc = RevisionControl.new remote: rc_url, local: dir
        rc.checkout version: prefix_tag(tag), force: true
        File.open(version_file, 'w') do |f|
          f.write tag
        end
      else
        rc = RevisionControl.new remote: rc_url, local: dir
        rc.checkout version: prefix_tag(tag), force: true
        FileUtils.touch "#{dir}/.initial_populate_successful"
        File.open(version_file, 'w') do |f|
          f.write tag
        end
      end
    rescue Origen::GitError, Origen::DesignSyncError => e
      # If Git failed in the remote, its usually easy to see what the problem is, but now *where* it is.
      # This will prepend the failing remote along with the error from the revision control system,
      # then rethrow the error
      e.message.prepend "When updating remotes for #{remote[:importer].name}: "
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```

The resolve_remotes! method just forces all known remotes to be fetched.  Would a PR be accepted for this solution?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remotes are currently required at application load time, which means it occurs before any of the application call back points.

The content of `config.remotes` can still be made dynamic by assigning it in a block:

```rb
config.remotes do
  r = [{
    dir: 'product',
    vault: 'ssh://git@stash.com/myproduct/origen.git',
    version: '0.1.0'
  }]

  if some_condition
    r << { dir: ... }
  end

  r      
end
```

The `config.remotes` attribute will be evaluated before the target is loaded however, so you won't be able to reference `dut` for example, though maybe that is good enough.

Alternatively, you could implement a post target require of the remotes within your application pretty easily.

Make the remotes return en empty array if the dut is not available yet, that will make it work ok when it is called by Origen during application load:

```rb
config.remotes do
  if dut
    # As above example
  else
    []
  end
end
```

Then within the callback handler of your choice:

```rb
Origen.remote_manager.require!
```

That should cause it to re-evaluate `config.remotes` and fetch any remotes that are missing.

Comment: thx @ginty.  I just need the remotes to be ready at the same time options from a target file are passed into the DUT initialization.  Is there any way to grab them in config/boot.rb?  It really is chicken and the egg as no matter where I put the remotes call, it is product specific.  :/ will have to stew on this a bit.

Comment: In that case I would recommend saving these options in a DUT attribute, dut.target_options for example. You can do that within an on_create callback in your DUT model (this will have these options passed in), and then you can call remote_manger.require! from there.